# Problem on this challenge

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {AFoundryCourseChallenge} from "AFoundryCourseChallenge.sol";

contract LessonOne is AFoundryCourseChallenge {
string private constant LESSON_IMAGE = "ipfs://QmYNk9TaRp9QDRjDZYxrwh5xQGMeC9zY23tB4fs5qby6KT";

constructor(address fcn) AFoundryCourseChallenge(fcn) {}

/*
 * CALL THIS FUNCTION!
 * 
 * @param yourTwitterHandle - Your twitter handle. Can be a blank string.
 */
function solveChallenge(string memory yourTwitterHandle) external {
    _updateAndRewardSolver(yourTwitterHandle);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////// The following are functions needed for the NFT, feel free to ignore. ///////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function description() external pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "Cyfrin Foundry Full Course: Awesome! You got the basics down! You minted an NFT!";
}

function attribute() external pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "Getting learned!";
}

function specialImage() external pure override returns (string memory) {
    return LESSON_IMAGE;
}
}
```

I wrote the solution(the location and newLocation uint256) in the solveChallenge, but still always gives me transaction failed, why?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?
Make sure to elaborate on your question.

Comment: The error is that,in metamask it says that the cost of gas it s high because it may be an error in the contract,why? I

Comment: Specify what function you are trying to call. Because there can be multiple reasons for this. Also click on proceed anyways and see the reason for the error, that will help in debugging easily.